# What is the general pattern for the number of inputs for which this algorithm performs t comparisons?

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to perform an average case analysis over this decision tree, which contains N items where N is a multiple of 4. I am struggling to make a generalization about the number of inputs which perform comparisons.

[A sketch of the Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHXwx.jpg)

Here is a table of the number of comparisons performed, the maximum number of comparisons K can be given by K = 2 + n/4.

[Number of comparisons performed for N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKQmi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of decisions for some input is the length of the path from that input node to the root.
If we go from $N$ to $N+4$, we push the original tree down to the right, i.e., increase each path length by $1$, and add four new nodes with path lengths $1$, $2$, $3$, $3$. Thus the number $a_{i,j}$ in your table in row $i$ of column $j$ is simply $a_{i-1,j-1}+a_{i,1}$.

The sum of all numbers of decisions accordingly behaves as follows:
$$ s(N+4)=9+s(N)+N$$
which easily leads to
$$ s(N)=\frac18N^2+\frac 74 N.$$
Divide by $N$ to obtain the average as
$$\frac{s(N)}N= \frac 18N+\frac 74.$$